# Opencart 1.5.5.1: Remove Hidden Products from Featured Module

Tags: php, if-statement, opencart

I set the featured module to show 8 products. I loaded 16 products into the featured module. When I disable one of the products that is showing on the webpage, it does not replace it with an enabled product. So there is an empty spot on the webpage.

I am not sure how to fix this. I was looking in the catalog/controller/module/featured.php around line 24:

```
foreach ($products as $product_id) {
         $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
```

I am thinking to wrap this foreach with an if else statement something like:

```
If ($product is disabled) {
     skip to next product 
}
else {
     foreach ($products as $product_id) {
              $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
     ...
     ...
     ...
}
```

I want to try something like this:

```
if ($product_id['status'] == 0) {
    no idea here
}
else{
     foreach ($products as $product_id) {
              $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
     ...
     ...
     ...
}
```

But again, not sure if `if ($product_id['status'] == 0)` is correct, or even what to do with the products inside the if statement if it is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see what you are saying. This is an oversight on the part of whoever wrote this module.

You need to filter disabled products before the limit is set, i.e.: in `catalog/controller/module/featured.php` find this line:

```
$products = array_slice($products, 0, (int)$setting['limit']);
```

Before, add:

```
// filter out disabled products befor setting limit

foreach ($products as $k => $v){
    $p_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($v);
    if ($p_info['status']==0) {
        unset ($products[$k]);
    }
}
```

That's all.
Good job on spotting this shortcoming by the way.

Comment: Perfect. I was going crazy.. trying if(){continue;} and looking at how to go off product_info['quantity'] == 0  and all sorts of other wrong things..... saved me an evening of stress, thanks again.